# Changing navbar height breaks responsive collapse?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I succesfully reduced the height of navbar, but after the resize browser - responsive collapse breaks.

Normally if it's in collapse mode it expands the navbar area so all of the dropdowns are within it. After changing height of the navbar it jumps out of the div and is missing most of
the properties

Are there any "tutorials" or guides how to successfully change the height of navbar without breaking responsiveness.

**Code used** :

```
.navbar, .navbar-header, .navbar-brand, .navbar-nav, 
.navbar-nav ul, .navbar-nav li, .navbar-nav>li>a {
    margin-top: 0px;
    min-height: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8ABj/)**

Comment: Can you set this up in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w8ABj/

Answer (score 3):

Use a media query to set the height only for screen widths above the @grid-float-breakpoint

LESS:

```
@media(min-width:@grid-float-breakpoint)
{   
.navbar {min-height:200px;}
}
```

CSS:

```
@media(min-width:768px)
{   
.navbar {min-height:200px;}
}
```

See also http://bootply.com/96446 (based on the code in your jsfiddle)

Comment: I think more the problem is that I haven't found the exact class to change. Some how the changes i made also restrict the "epxansion" size resulting in a dropdown area which is outside the original DIV(s)

Comment: I needed to add include {.navbar **.navbar-inner** {min-height:200px;}} to make it work. @Slidemouth even if you change `@navbar-height` in Less?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS you can use :

```
/* Navbar height */
.navbar {
    min-height: 28px;
}
.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    line-height: 26px;
    padding: 1px 5px;
}
/* Toggle button size */
.navbar-toggle {
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    width: 14px;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar+.icon-bar {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

**[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/w8ABj/3/)**

Note : I put a `margin-top` on the navbar to avoid the "Result" label.